# Flash: making an interactable image

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Im trying to figure out how to take an image and make it interactable in different parts.
The image is a bunch of arrows that make a circle, and, what I want to happen is when a particular arrow is hovered over it enlarges the arrows and hovers over the two adjacent arrows.

I imported the image from illustrator to flash onto a single frame and made each arrow a button, with the down image an enlarged version, but it appears that the images are on separate layers somehow?
when I go to hover over one of the arrows, it is under one arrow but over another.

How would I get the hovered over arrow to be always on top of all of the other images in the movie?

**Maybe a code that, onHover  brought the symbol to the front of the stage?**

Comment: You should probably ask this on http://flashkit.com or http://actionscript.org, places where you can attach a .fla and people can look more closely at what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I think you are quite right here, as well. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about the structure of you flash app/movie but I think you would do something along the line of the following:

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onArrowMouseOver);
arrow.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, onArrowMouseOut);

function onArrowMouseOver(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var arrow:Sprite = Sprite(e.target);
    setChildIndex(arrow, this.numChildren-1);
    arrow.scaleX = arrow.scaleY = 2;
}

function onArrowMouseOut(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var arrow:Sprite = Sprite(e.target);
    arrow.scaleX = arrow.scaleY = 1;
}
```

Comment: This will work, too, but you have to add the listener to each arrow instance, and it's not reusable.

Comment: For that, you can create an array or vector of arrow objects and add listeners to each arrow instance using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener function to react on MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, which will bring the button to front.

Create MyButton.as (code below) to hold a class that extends SimpleButton and add the listener function there.  Then set MyButton as base class for the arrow symbol in the properties panel.

```
package {

    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class MyButton extends SimpleButton {
        private function onMouseOver ( ev:MouseEvent ) : void {
            parent.setChildIndex (this, parent.numChildren -1);
        }

        public function MyButton () {
            addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onMouseOver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that you should check to see if the `MyButton` object's `stage` property is null indicating whether the `MyButton` object has been added to the display list. If you add a `MyButton` object programmatically, you'll get an error because the `parent` property will be null and your trying to access its properties/methods.

Comment: No, parent will not be null, because it is called inside the event handler function - there will not be a MOUSE_OVER event, unless the mouse is actually OVER the button, which can only happen after it was added to the stage.